# stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR, while using Retrofit in 3G network

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, okhttp

Good noon everyone!

I am using `Retrofit` for networking calls in my application. The app is really working fine with great speed. Thanks for the wonderful library. But, It is working only in wi-fi. If i run the app in 3G network, throwing the error. `stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR,  while using Retrofit in 3G network`

I have imported this jar files to the build path :

[image]

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595): java.io.IOException: stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy.SpdyStream.getResponseHeaders(SpdyStream.java:146)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SpdyTransport.readResponseHeaders(SpdyTransport.java:109)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:676)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:426)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:371)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:466)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at $Proxy0.getLoginCredentials(Native Method)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.connected.merchant.SignIn$SignMeIn.doInBackground(SignIn.java:197)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at com.connected.merchant.SignIn$SignMeIn.doInBackground(SignIn.java:1)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-17 16:01:54.017: D/Retrofit(3595): ---- END ERROR
```

Google didn't help me. It would be really great if you help me to sort this out. Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes i did,Actually, Jesse helped me, Do mention if you need the workaround. It was a bug in okHttp Jar file.

Comment: Can you please provide details of the workaround?

Comment: @Shree Please check [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1156) I wonder why do you want to use old version though..

Answer (score 6):

I solved a similar problem by restricting the request to use HTTP 1, see:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
```

Comment: Don't know why it fixed it, but it did.

Comment: It is about SSL negotiation, that typically occurs between an HTTP server and an Android OS when you are requesting any API. 
When you specify the HTTP protocol version as HTTP 1.1, you are indicating your preference for communication using that specific version. The TLS/SSL server can accept the connection if it is configured to support it; otherwise, it may reject the connection during the SSL handshake process

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in either OkHtttp or your webserver's implementation of SPDY or HTTP/2. Upgrade to OkHttp/2.1. If that doesn't fix it, open an issue on OkHttp's issue tracker & include the hostname of the server that's causing you grief.

Comment: OkHttp-2.1 doesn't help me.